# How to process an iFormFile with ClosedXML with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-5.0, closedxml, iformfile

I want to load an excel file into XLWorkbook

```
using var workbook = new XLWorkbook("iFormFile needs to go here");
var ws = workbook.Worksheet(1);
```

Answer (score 5):

There can be better answers than this, but this should work.

```
using var workbook = new XLWorkbook(iFormFile.OpenReadStream());
var ws = workbook.Worksheet(1);
```